# Is there any way to recover from Psych::SyntaxError?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, yaml

When there is a syntax error in an i18n locale YAML file, `Psych::SyntaxError` is raised. When this exception is encountered during Rails bootup (for example, when production is restarted), Rails crashes.

1. Is there any way to capture this exception and somehow recover from it without having Rails crash altogether?
2. Is there any way to check locale files for syntax errors before commit or deploy in an automated way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to recover from this error, but I've created a rake task that ensures that a given YAML file is syntactically valid (run via a pre-commit git hook for any changed YAML files):

```
namespace :yaml do
  desc "Check YAML syntax for errors."
  task :check_syntax do
    require 'YAML'
    require 'colorize'

    puts "Checking YAML files..."

    filenames = (ENV['FILENAMES'].split(',') || []).push(ENV['FILENAME']).uniq.compact
    fails = 0

    filenames.each do |file|
      print "#{file}... "

      begin
        YAML.load_file(file)
      rescue Psych::SyntaxError => e
        fails += 1
        print "Failed! ".red
        print "[#{e.message.sub(/\A.*: /, '')}]"
        puts
        next
      end

      print "Success!".green
      puts
    end

    puts

    exit fails > 0 ? 1 : 0
  end
end
```